# FXCop report hosting on Hudson Dashboard Issue

Tags: plugins, hudson, report, fxcop, dashboard

I generated Fxcop analysis report using ant script. But I am unable to host it on Hudson Dashboard.
Using Nant script, I am able to generate an .xml output. Here is the ant:

```
<target name="Fxcop">
    <echo message="Running Fxcop..." />
    <exec command="${fxcop.basedir}\FxCopCmd.exe">
      <arg value="/f:Path of my source file/>
      <arg value="/out:some path/>
    </exec>
  </target>
```

In hudson Configuration, To display Vioaltion Reports, i configured the path of output(only pattern) file of the ant in xml file pattern of fxcop.
But Hudson is unable to find it.
I done the configurations and setting correctly.
Can anyone walk me through where I am going wrong.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using the [Violations](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations) plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely XML is created in different subfolder which relative path is originated from current directory. E.g. if your current working directory is `%WORKSPACE%\trunk` and relative path for report is `/out:result\fxcop-result.xml` then it will be created in `%WORKSPACE%\trunk\result\fxcop-result.xml`. 
To fix this I suggest to check current directory from which you are executing FxCop analysis (also try searching this xml on build machine).

Easiest way to implement FxCop analysis in Hudson using Windows batch command will be:

1. Add "Execute Windows batch command" (this command will be executed from base workspace folder, e.g. C:\hudson\workspace\FxCopJob)
2. Specify command that will execute analysis, e.g.: `""{FxCopDirectory}\fxcopcmd.exe" /file:"%WORKSPACE%\{path to your file}" /directory="{Assemblies_path}" /rulesetdirectory:"{RuleSetDir}" /out:fxcop-result.xml"`
3. Set `fxcop-result.xml` in fxcop section of Report Violation (e.g. report will be created in C:\hudson\workspace\FxCopJob\fxcop-result.xml)
4. Run updated Hudson job and verify that FxCop violations are shown

*WBR,
Andrey*